# Why does my code note create 4 separate threads at different intervals?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

I want to generate 4 separate threads that write to the console.

I thought that this code would execute a process at n intervals, which means that the first `Console.WriteLine` would execute after 1 minute, the second one after 4 minutes, and so on.

```
private static void CopyFiles()
{
    string strCmdText;
    strCmdText= @"xcopy C:\Users\Me\Documents\Files\*.* C:\Users\Me\Documents\Files\JustTest";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
}       
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestThreads();
}
static void TestThreads()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Begin TestThreads");
    int firstQtr = 1;
    int secondQtr = 4;
    int thirdQtr = 6;

    if (firstQtr >= 0)
    {
        System.Threading.Timer t0 = new Timer((s) =>
        {
            CopyFiles();
        }, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(firstQtr), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
    }
    if (secondQtr >= 0)
    {
        System.Threading.Timer t1 = new Timer((s) =>
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }

        }, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(secondQtr), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
    }
    if (thirdQtr >= 0)
    {
        System.Threading.Timer t2 = new Timer((s) =>
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }

        }, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(thirdQtr), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
    }
}
```

I don't see any output in the console window, either by debugging or running directly from the command prompt.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aren't the timers started in the constructor with `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int)`? In this case, after 4 minutes `System.Threading.Timer t1` would begin executing.

Comment: Since none of the delegates will complete, the 1ms period is not very significant.

Comment: Does the command prompt immediately exit? or is it sitting there not outputting anything. Basically, can you show us the code that calls `TestThreads()`?

Comment: It's a console application, looks like this: `static void Main(string[] args) { TestThreads(); }`

Comment: The command prompt immediately exits, that's why I know nothing's running.

Comment: Since I'm using `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int)`, it's 1 minute, right?

Comment: Your main program doesn't wait for the threads, it just exits. That takes down the process with all of its threads.

Comment: I modified the code so that it does something relevant, xcopy files. I assumed that even if it immediately exits, the timers were already initiated.

Answer (score 2):

When the main method exits the only (foreground) thread in the process exits. When that happens the CLR shuts down the process. Make your main method stay active, for example by halting it:

```
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

(Hope, I remembered that right.)

Timers do not use threads and they invoke the callback on a background thread-pool thread. They do not keep a process alive.